# Calling a function of the current UIViewController when using SWRevealViewController

Tags: swift, cllocation, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an app written in swift that displays location information on different views. I am receiving location updates in `AppDelegate` (I don't want to use a singleton class since I want the location updates even when the app is in the background).

Now, I am using `SWRevealViewController` to implement a sidebar menu to toggle between the different views. When a new location update is received, how do I call the function of the viewController that is currently active to update the UI?

I searched a lot and all the solutions that talk about how to find the current `UIViewController` actually return `SWRevealViewController` as the current `UIViewController`, which doesn't help.

Comment: showing code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I gave it another shot and was able to find my viewController in my app from another view controller. However, I couldn't get my child view controllers app delegate.

Looking forward to other answers...

here's what I did:

```
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate
    if let nav = app.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers {
        nav.forEach { vc in
            if let viewControllers = vc as? UINavigationController {
                viewControllers.childViewControllers.forEach { vc in
                    if let x = vc as? ViewController {
                        print("Got it \(x)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```